# Parsing local JSON file with search String

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

really need your help.

I'm trying to parse local JSON file (list of cities) using search String, I want to get back a selective set of data, which is relevant to my search String, i.e. I type in the name of the city, and get back the list of cities that match the String from the JSON file.

Usually when the data is on the web it is very easy to do such operation by simply adding a  query parameter in URL, however I'm not sure how to do it when parsing local JSON file.

Here's my code to parse the whole file:

```
guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "cityList", ofType: "json") else {
        fatalError("Failed to create path to cityList file")
    }
    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

    do {
        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        let cityList = try JSONDecoder().decode([City].self, from: jsonData)
        print(cityList[0].name)

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

I'm hoping I don't have to parse the whole file, as it is quite big, and then apply the search to the resulting array of data I get back from parsing.

Comment: no issue there, I just don't know how to only get a list of certain cities out of the json file, and not the list of all the cities in the list, as the list in the json file is massive.

Answer (score 1):

Just `filter` the array

```
let query = "New"
let filteredCities = cityList.filter{$0.name.range(of: query, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil) }
```

This syntax filters all cities which contain `new` (case insensitive) in their name.

If you want to filter the cities which **start** with `new` add the `.anchored` option

```
let filteredCities = cityList.filter{$0.name.range(of: query, options: [.caseInsensitive, .anchored]) != nil) }
```

---

And there is an API `url(forResource:withExtension:)` in `Bundle` which returns an URL

Comment: Thank you for the reply good sir, but as I said, I want to retrieve only certain list of cities from the original json file, NOT retrieve the whole list of cities, and then filter out the cities I need,  the reason for that being that the json file contains just enormous amount of data.

Comment: @Gideon that's not possible with a file - you need to read the whole file to know if the data you are searching for is in there.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, so would be wise to extract all the data from the json file and store it in some other format, in order to make the searching as least time consuming as possible?